# Lodash Remove objects from array by matching ids array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like:

```
var a = [
  {id: 1, name: 'A'},
  {id: 2, name: 'B'},
  {id: 3,  name: 'C'},
  {id: 4, name: 'D'}
];
```

And Ids array which i want to remove from array a :

```
var removeItem = [1,2];
```

I want to remove objects from `array a` by matching its ids, which `removeItem array` contains. How can i implement with lodash.

I Checked lodash's [_.remove](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#remove) method, but this need a specific condition to remove an item from array. But i have list of ids which i want to remove.

Comment: without lodash - `a.filter( item => removeItem.indexOf( item.id ) == -1  );`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you mentioned you need the `_.remove` method and the specific condition you mention is whether the `removeItem` array contains the `id` of the checked element of the array.

```
var removeElements = _.remove(a, obj => removeItem.includes(obj.id));
// you only need to assign the result if you want to do something with the removed elements.
// the a variable now holds the remaining array
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass a `predicate` function to `.remove` method from `lodash`.

```
var final = _.remove(a, obj => removeItem.indexOf(obj.id) > -1);
```

using `indexOf` method.

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
>   can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

You can do it using `native` javascript using `filter` method which accepts as parameter a **callback** function.

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, name: 'A'},
  {id: 2, name: 'B'},
  {id: 3,  name: 'C'},
  {id: 4, name: 'D'}
];
var removeItem = [1,2];
a = a.filter(function(item){ 
   return removeItem.indexOf( item.id ) == -1; 
});
console.log(a);
```

But `filter` method just creates a new array by applying a **callback** function.

From **documentation**:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

If you want to modify the original array use `splice` method.

```js
var a = [
  {id: 1, name: 'A'},
  {id: 2, name: 'B'},
  {id: 3,  name: 'C'},
  {id: 4, name: 'D'}
];
var removeItem = [1,2];
removeItem.forEach(function(id){
   var itemIndex = a.findIndex(i => i.id == id);
   a.splice(itemIndex,1);
});
console.log(a);
```